# IDA 7 handling strings in debugger pseudocode

Tags: ida, x86, decompilation, c++, hexrays

When running a remote debugger to a linux server, is there a way to get IDA (7.0) to properly handle strings? When I go to the pseudocode view, I get things like this;

```
v7 = sub_804AD60((std::string *)&v16);
char *v5;
```

So clearly IDA has some handling of string types, and it's able to infer that one of these is a C++ string and the other a pointer to a C string. What I can't figure out is how to get that string? I've been searching for a locals window or something in the debugger with no luck, and hovering over `v16` gets an `int v16` with a memory address value. Surely there's some way to just get the actual string value of `v16` or `v5` in plain old ASCII or UTF-8 without having to dig it out of the hex view?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! For `v5` you should be shown the value, but for something like a `std::string` it depends. I have IDA, but not the HexRays plugin, so I can't be of much help here.

Comment: Sometimes, we've to guess the data type. You can get the data type while debugging. Then press Y to change it.

Comment: The datatype is spot-on, it's 100% an std::string, but that string -- `Hello World\0`, should be somehow visible to me, and yet I can't find a way.

Comment: Locate a cursor on v16, press <kbd>Y</kbd>, enter std::string, press enter.